# Does the implementation of the .NET Generic.Dictionary use a balanced binary tree?

Tags: .net, binary-tree

As I load many items into a .NET Dictionary, do I need to worry about the internal implementation or can I assume that it uses something like a balanced binary tree to assure searching is fast?

Comment: No. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table

Comment: The underlying implementation is a hash map. The read performance will vary (albeit probably negligibly) with the implementation of the hashing method of the type of the key.

Comment: @Cᴏʀʏ Not really, unless your hashing method is really totally rubbish. :-) Once you get too many collisions, it multiplies with another value, which ensures the distribution is more uniformly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the [source for Dictionary](https://github.com/Microsoft/referencesource/blob/master/mscorlib/system/collections/generic/dictionary.cs).

You don't need to worry about the internal implementation of anything in the .NET Framework until it's actually an issue. There are some smart folks working at Microsoft who have done a decent, though not always perfect, job of optimizing things like collections. They're such a basic feature of the platform that you can expect them to have undergone rigorous development and testing.

When it comes to dictionaries and suchlike things, the Object class itself (and hence everything else in .NET) has a .GetHashCode() method. This is used as a hash function primarily for use with dictionaries and similar keyed collections. The long and short of it is, as you'll see in the linked source code, that dictionaries in .NET are implemented as hashtables, not trees.

Performance of a dictionary/hashtable data structure in .NET depends on multiple factors, including the level of defensive programming checks used, whether concurrency must be supported with locking and lock-avoidance techniques, and the efficiency of the storage and retrieval operations.

The hash function itself can be a non-negligible part of this; here, for example, is [a faster implementation of .GetHashCode() for .NET strings](https://bitbucket.org/jeff_varszegi/sharpbyte-net-public/src/f6bc1e2fc59993ae76e3afc248bee364ba189809/SharpByte.Core/Collections/Specialized/StringExtensions.cs?at=master&fileviewer=file-view-default#StringExtensions.cs-115), just to show that yes, you can sometimes eke out a small bit of extra performance here and there.

However, extreme performance tuning is not generally necessary unless you're writing some sort of high-performance API for reuse, or other similar code with a specific application where every cycle counts, the code may be used in a tight loop, or whatever. The performance of your code will by far depend more on your correct use and knowledge of things like data structures, than on the specific performance of a reference implementation from Redmond.